# Django-Filebrowser: Getting an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Tags: django, django-filebrowser

I'm searching what is the reason for getting this AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endswith'.

I have Django 1.3 installed and trying to use the PIP install of Django-Filebrowser and when I try to syncdb or runserver I get this traceback. Can anyone tell me how to fix this? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Found I needed to add a '/' to the settings file before 'filebrowser/' like so '/filebrowser/'

Answer (score 3):

I had the same trouble, and have fixed by configuring the STATIC_URL in my Django settings file.